# Issue creating an array of UIImages

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, uiimage

I am trying to create an array of UIImages but I am getting the error:

```
TableViewController.type does not have a member named squatImage
```

I am trying to create an array so I can add a different image to each cell of a tableView I have.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?
    var tableData = ["Squats","Bench Press","Bent Over Row","Barbell Shrugs","Tricep Extensions","Straight Bar","Hyperextensions","Cable Crunches"]


    var squatImage = UIImage(named:"First.png")!
    var squatImage2 = UIImage(named:"Second.png")!

    var tableImages: [UIImage] = [squatImage, squatImage2]



    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PickerTableViewCell
        cell.titleLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
//        cell.imageView.image = "First.png"

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
var tableImages: [UIImage] = [squatImage, squatImage2]
```

You're trying to access the member variable `squatImage` (and `squatImage2`), before Swift has had a chance to know that `squatImage` is actually defined as a member of your `TableViewController` class.

If you define your `tableImages` array in your `viewDidLoad` method instead (i.e., at runtime), your code will work.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes sense however I don't have a viewDidLoad method, what should I do? Would I just define it as `var tableImages: [UIImage]`  and then change the problem line to  `tableImages = [squatImage, squatImage2]`

Comment: I just added the viewDidLoad method and I think it's working fine :)

Comment: Exactly. Declare your `tableImages` as optional: `var tableImages: [UIImage]?`  and override `viewDidLoad` and define it as you suggested

Comment: Would you mind if I asked you a different question on chat about assigning the uiimageview a different image for each cell?

Comment: Make a new question on SO and sure :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557420/how-can-i-assign-a-different-uiimage-in-each-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Instead of defining UIImage separately do this:

```
 var tableImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named:"First.png")!, UIImage(named:"Second.png")!]
```

**Solution 2:** if you want to set images separately and insert it in array then  Define an empty array:

```
  var squatImage = UIImage(named:"First.png")!
  var squatImage2 = UIImage(named:"Second.png")!

  var tableImages: [UIImage] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      tableImages = [squatImage,squatImage2]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```