# How can I assign a different UIImage in each UITableViewCell?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am struggling to figure out how exactly I can display a different image in each UITableViewCell.

I currently have a UIImageView in an expanding / collapsing UITableViewCell in my storyboard. I can assign an image to them all by defining the image in the attributes for this UIImageView but that shows the same image in each cell (obviously).

This is the code I have for TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

let cellID = "cell"



class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?
    var tableData = ["Squats","Bench Press","Bent Over Row","Barbell Shrugs","Tricep Extensions","Straight Bar","Hyperextensions","Cable Crunches"]


    var squatImage = UIImage(named:"First.png")!
    var squatImage2 = UIImage(named:"First.png")!

    var tableImages: [UIImage] = []


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PickerTableViewCell

        cell.titleLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

//        cell.imageView?.image = self.tableImages[0]
// **This does NOT work**, it assigns a picture into each cell and on each cells title. 


        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableImages = [squatImage,squatImage2]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }

        var indexPaths : Array<NSIndexPath> = []
        if let previous = previousIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [previous]
        }
        if let current = selectedIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [current]
        }
        if indexPaths.count > 0 {
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        (cell as! PickerTableViewCell).watchFrameChanges()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        (cell as! PickerTableViewCell).ignoreFrameChanges()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            return PickerTableViewCell.expandedHeight
        } else {
            return PickerTableViewCell.defaultHeight
        }
    }


}
```

and for PickerTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class PickerTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    class var expandedHeight: CGFloat { get { return 200 } }
    class var defaultHeight: CGFloat  { get { return 44  } }

    @IBOutlet weak var squatImage: UIImageView!

    func checkHeight() {
        squatImage.hidden = (frame.size.height < PickerTableViewCell.expandedHeight)
    }

    func watchFrameChanges() {
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New|NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: nil)
    }

    func ignoreFrameChanges() {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if keyPath == "frame" {
            checkHeight()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `cell.imageView?.image = self.tableImages[indexPath.row]`? You need to keep an 8 different images within `tableImages`.

Comment: Okay it's working but this is happening (why is the picture also in the title)? http://i.imgur.com/0L14213.png. They expand properly but its also putting the image in the title.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
        cell.titleLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView?.image = self.tableImages[indexPath.row % 2] 
        return cell
}
```

Comment: `var squatImage = UIImage(named:"First.png")!
    var squatImage2 = UIImage(named:"First.png")!`
    you assigned same image for two objects
maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Okay it's working but this is happening (why is the picture also in the title)? http://i.imgur.com/0L14213.png. They expand properly but its also putting the image in the title.

Comment: just create horizontal space constraint between image and label, if you not familiar try this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/83130/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-2

Comment: I don't think I explained very well. Those small images are just sitting there in each title. When I click on the cell it expands and a big image shows up where it should but that small image is also there overlaying.